# List of inequalities for purity of a traced out bipartite system

Tags: entanglement, density-matrix, linear-algebra, purification

I would like to know if there are inequalities related to the purity of the partial trace of a bipartite system.
The purity $P$ of a density matrix $\rho$ is given by
$$P(\rho) = Tr(\rho^2).$$
The most trivial inequality is $1/n \leq P \leq 1$, where $n$ is the dimension of a system.

Given a bipartite system $AB$ and the respective density matrix $\rho$, I would like to know if there are any inequalities or formulas relating
$P(Tr_B(\rho))$ and $P(Tr_A(\rho))$ or $P(Tr_A(M \rho M^{\dagger}))$ where $M$ is any arbitrary operator.

Any references and links to the list of relations are very much appreciated!